# Anchor hidden div when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, css, anchor, hidden-field

I have three buttons all of which contain hidden content. When a button is clicked, I want that specific content to display and hide all other content. I also want the screen to jump down to the content that shows when clicking on the button.

What do I need to add to the JavaScript to make it jump down to the content? Here is what I have:

```js
$("#wrap div[id^='Template']").click(function() {
  var active = $(this).attr('id');
  $(this).siblings("[class^='Template']:not(." + active + ")").hide();
  $(this).siblings("." + active).slideToggle();
});
```

```css
#Template2,
#Template3,
#Template4 {
  margin-top: 24px;
  margin-left: 19% !important;
  background-color: #cb3778;
  padding: 0 30px 0 30px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 36px;
  float: left;
  color: #FFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8;
  -moz-border-radius: 8;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
.Template2,
.Template3,
.Template4 {
  display: none;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="display: block;" id="wrap">

  <div id="Template2">Sample 2</div>
  <div id="Template3">Sample 3</div>
  <div id="Template4">Sample 4</div>

  <div align="center" style="padding-top:40px;" class="Template2">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>sample demo txt two 2</div>
  <div align="center" style="padding-top:40px;" class="Template3">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>sample demo txt two 3</div>
  <div align="center" style="padding-top:40px;" class="Template4">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>sample demo txt two 4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to the end of the click function.

```
$("body, html").animate({
    scrollTop: $(this).siblings("." + active).position().top
});
```

Comment: Ok, so after pasting it did scroll down when there was enough space to put it further down the page, but how do I make it scroll down so that the top of the hidden div will be at the top of the window?

Comment: it should do that if there is enough content below the element to allow it to scroll to the top of the window. Have a look at https://jsfiddle.net/scoon1329/hhfsvhqj/

Answer (score 0):

How about using CSS `:target` pseudo-class. See: http://codepen.io/zvona/pen/YwdGrW

```
.content {
  visibility: hidden;  
}

.content:target {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: I like this option, is there anyway it can replace the div so that all content displays in the same area when visible?

Comment: Use `display:none` and `display:block` instead if you want to set all content on same position.